# What determines how long an app takes to install? Android

Tags: android, installation, adb

I'm using eclipse and am currently working on an android app. When I first started developing, after the upload through ADB finished, the app would install and start almost instantly, now it is taking a consistent 12 seconds. 
I was wondering about what determines the time it takes for an app to install on a device once it has been uploaded?

Edit: Just tested this on 3 different android devices, all 3 take exactly 12 seconds.
My apk file size is 378kb.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? :) An APK file is basically a ZIP file with a .apk extension so obviously the installation process includes unpacking. If you've added a lot of resources (drawables etc) or added files to the raw or assets directories then they're going to increase the unpacking time.

Comment: @Squonk But my apk size is only 350~kb, should that really be taking 12 seconds?

Comment: @NeoMime : But that's the compressed size. If you a lot of small files in there which have been compressed to a great extent it will take a long time to go through each and decompress them. You can test this yourself with ZIP files. Put 1000 1KB text files into a ZIP file. The compression of text files is normally very high and the ZIP will be much smaller than the combined uncompressed 1MB. When you uncompress, the operation requires unpacking and uncompressing 1000 highly compressed files takes a lot of time. On an aside ADB isn't particularly efficient for installation purposes.

Comment: @Squonk Fair enough, perhaps the number of file affects the wait. I have quite a few layouts that I created, perhaps that's it? 
Also, is your name from an anime? I feel like I recognize it.

Comment: @NeoMime : No, my name is from a song by Genesis on the album "A Trick of the Tail". It was my nickname when I was an Electronics apprentice many years ago.